# Which research languages have a stronger typesystem than Haskell and why?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory

[Here](https://github.com/Gabriel439/post-rfc/blob/master/sotu.md#type-system) I read that:

> Haskell definitely does not have the most advanced type system (not
>   even close if you count research languages) but out of all languages
>   that are actually used in production Haskell is probably at the top.

So I am asking two things:

1. which research languages have more powerful type systems  than Haskell;
2. what do they improve.

I am just a programmer, so I don't know many mathematical objects used in type theory, please provide gentle explanations if you can.

Comment: What's "better"?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I guess that means _more powerful type system_

Comment: Once you have proven that [a type system is Turing-complete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189172), does it really matter? ;-)

Comment: Turing machines are Turing-complete, why don't you use them for your everyday programming tasks?

Comment: @DevSolar so compilers and cross-compilers are a waste of time?

Comment: @VitalijZadneprovskij: Not at all. Just poking some self-deprecating fun at my language of choice, which certainly won't win any beauty contests. ;-)

Comment: Do note that the original text mentions languages with *more advanced* type systems and does not make any assertions wether 'more advanced' is better or worse for a type system.

Comment: @Peteris yes, but that is the reason why it is not considered _best in class_, but only _mature_.

Comment: This question feels to me like it might be too broad.  In general, questions that ask for a big list of X (e.g., a list of all languages with some property) are frequently considered too broad and [not a good fit for this site](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/487/755).  Community votes, anyone?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The question is somewhat problematic, since it relies on a subjective definition of "better."

Dependently-typed languages such as [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php), [Idris](http://www.idris-lang.org/), and [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/) have a stronger type system than Haskell. This means, you can use the types in these languages to prove strictly more properties about your code than in Haskell. That is, there are more incorrect programs that will be caught.

However, this comes at a price: type inference, and testing whether any values of a given type exist, are no longer possible. This means for these languages, you need to explicitly annotate your code with types. Essentially this boils down to writing your own correctness proofs for your code.

So are these languages "better" than Haskell? They can check advanced proofs of correctness for your code, but they can't automatically prove properties about your code the way Haskell can.

Another research language that is "better" than Haskell is [LiquidHaskell](https://ucsd-progsys.github.io/liquidhaskell-blog/). This is basically Haskell with refinement types bolted on top, parsed from special comments.

Refinement types allow you you refine types with properties. For example, instead of having an `Int`, you can specify `{i : Int | i > 0}`, giving the type of all positive integers. Type inference is decidable with refinement types, but you can't prove nearly as many correctness properties with them as you can with dependent types.

There are other refinement type systems out there, but I'm not terribly familiar with any of them.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to prove that Haskell type system is the strongest one that still allows type inference?

Comment: Haskell's definitely is NOT the strongest that allows type inference. The refinement types I've mentioned allow for type inference, and many GHC extensions are being added to Haskell which allow for a slightly stronger type system.

Comment: On top of this, there are many type systems, and many are incomparable: they will be stronger than Haskell in some ways, but weaker than Haskell in others. There's not a linear ordering of type systems from strongest to weakest.

Comment: Now I want to prove there is no strongest type system that allows type inference. Must resist proving useless facts.

Comment: The fact doesn't seem useless to me. Knowledge that there exists a strongest type system with type inference would be of great interest, especially if it turned out to be feasible to implement.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I think you can do it, because for any type system, pick a piece of code that is type-correct (throws no error) but is untypeable, and add it as a special case to your type system. Any system with inference could be extended with an arbitrary number of special cases, and systems that don't agree on special cases would be incomparable.

Comment: @rationalis But that is almost certainly not true. It's a negative result, that's really only useful in that it tells us to stop looking for a positive result.

Comment: @jmite Well, yes. My point was exactly that - if a positive result is useful, then of course we would like to prove it, and then by association the negative result is worth proving as well.

Answer (score 10):

The ML family of languages (StandardML, [OCaml](https://ocaml.org)) arise from a similar tradition as Haskell and therefore have similar type systems. They are not exactly the same as Haskell, though, and some of their features might suit you better (there is no such thing as an *objectively better* type system because type systems in programming languages exist to help *humans*). Here are some features of OCaml that Haskell either does not have (but might have a corresponding similar concept), or Haskell does have but done differently:

1. [Polymorphic variants](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/variants.html#polymorphic-variants).
2. [Objects](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/objects.html) with [depth subtyping](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/objects.html#depth-subtyping) and [classes](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/classes.html).
3. [Functors](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/functors.html), which are maps between [modules](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/files-modules-and-programs.html) (Haskell has modules), and even [first-class modules](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/first-class-modules.html)

And please, there is no need to turn this into an ML-Haskell shootout, or else I will start linking to Bob Harper's blog posts ;-)

Answer (score 9):

The research language [Clean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_%28programming_language%29) has a better type system than Haskell, because it has [uniqueness types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_type). The ideas behind uniqueness types are closely related to [linear logic](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/topics/linear-logic.html), which is closer to the resource limited "real world" than classical logic.

The anti-research language [Rust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_%28programming_language%29) also has a type system with unique features that are closer to the "real world" than classical pure type systems. Most of the ideas which influenced the type system have been published completely independent of Rust long before it even existed. But the way these old ideas are put together is unique, and would also deserve real research publications, even if known loopholes and inconsistencies exist.

Comment: Somehow "published" and "anti-research" do not go together well.

Comment: Uniqueness is certainly an interesting concept, but IMO it's more about semantics, rather than a type system feature as such. And does this really make the type system strictly _better_? Can Clean do the newer stuff Haskell has added to its type system, higher-rank polymorphism etc. – are some of these even possible when the type system already needs to deal with uniqueness?

Comment: @leftaroundabout How familiar are you with uniqueness types or linear logic? If x has a unique type, then f(x,x) is not well typed, for example. It might be possible to extend Haskell to also support uniqueness types. The move semantics in C++ might also be seen as improving the support for uniquencess types on top of an existing type system.

Comment: I am familiar with C++ move semantics, perhaps that's why my impression of uniqueness is as “not much of a type-system thing”. What I'd find interesting is, do full outward-propagating uniqueness types hinder other features of advanced type system?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Rvalue references sound like a type-system thing to me. Why should uniqueness types hinder other advanced type features? In the worst case, those advanced features would simply not apply to uniqueness types. Of course, "real world" features like uniqueness types means going for breadth instead of depth, and the time you spend for going broader will no longer be there for going deeper. But I have the impression that uniqueness types offer a nice balance between theory and practice, so I think the time would be well spend.